# Showing Crystal report error

Tags: crystal-reports

This following error is raise when run the program

```
  Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer' exists in both 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\10.5.3700.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll' and 'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\CrystalDecisions.Web\13.0.2000.0__692fbea5521e1304\CrystalDecisions.Web.dll'
```

What is problem please help some one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is two type of version are avaliable like version:13.0.2000.0 and version :10.5.3700.0
So Remove any one reference from your project version 10 or 13 and also in aspx pages.